# Offlineimap stops retrieving after first 20-30 messages

Tags: imap, mutt, maildir

I have been trying to set up [offlineimap](http://offlineimap.org) to sync mail from gmail to the local folders on my mac machine.

The issue with my current set-up is that, offlineimap will start to sync the mail from both accounts, I can see lines like -

```
Copy message 3 (3 of 10966) repo1_remote:[Gmail]/Important -> repo1_local
```

But, after around 20-30 `copy message`, these lines just stop. Offlineimap is still connected though, it refreshes after 10 minutes and syncs again but, I cant see any more `copy message` lines in the repos any longer, it just stops. I can see these new 20-30 new messages in mutt, but not more. Killing and restarting offlineimap agains copies 20-30 new messages and again stops. I have no clue as to what is wrong. I guess it should copy all messages locally. Here is my `offlineimaprc`. I have the python file set up correctly.

```
[general]
metadata = ~/.offlineimap
accounts = repo1, repo2
maxsyncaccounts = 10
#ui = blinkenlights
ui = ttyui
pythonfile = ~/Development/OfflineIMAP/mail/offlineimap.py
#socktimeout = 60

[mbnames]

[Account repo2]

localrepository = repo2_local
remoterepository = repo2_remote
autorefresh = 10
status_backend = sqlite
synclabels = yes

[Account repo1]

localrepository = repo1_local
remoterepository = repo1_remote
autorefresh = 10
status_backend = sqlite
synclabels = yes

[Repository repo2_local]

type = GmailMaildir
nametrans = get_remote_name
localfolders = ~/Development/OfflineIMAP/mail/repo2
sep = /
restoreatime = yes

[Repository repo1_local]

type = GmailMaildir
nametrans = get_remote_name
localfolders = ~/Development/OfflineIMAP/mail/repo1
sep = /
restoreatime = yes

[Repository repo2_remote]
type = Gmail
folderfilter = is_included
nametrans = get_local_name
cert_fingerprint = 3ffdb8519c1c8242ce8387d3d9fccc208a776b4a
remoteuser = asd@gmail.com
remotepasseval = get_password('asd')
usecompression = yes
maxconnections = 3

[Repository repo1_remote]
type = Gmail
folderfilter = is_included
nametrans = get_local_name
cert_fingerprint = 3ffdb8519c1c8242ce8387d3d9fccc208a776b4a
remoteuser = qwe@gmail.com
remotepasseval = get_password('qwe')
usecompression = yes
maxconnections = 3
```

I would like to know what is preventing offlineimap from copying further messages and what should I change in the config to make it work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just recently ran into the same problem with gmail. In my case disabling compression and setting connections limit to 1 resolved the issue (didn't have time to investigate fully). Have you tried doing this?